# Download s3 files without using cli from specific IP sources

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I have a requirement to download a file (as ex: https://hematestpolicy.s3.amazonaws.com/test/ca-dev2.png)   s3 object across many instances in my aws vpc without having to install aws cli. The file should be protected, can be accessed only within VPC. I have applied below bucket policy on my s3 bucket hematestpolicy. Am able to view the file in my instances using aws s3 ls commands but unable to download it using wget command. Can anyone suggest if it is achievable or a better solution for file being private to vpc and downloaded without use of AWS CLI

`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "CreditApplications",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreditAppProcessing",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::975472539761:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::975472539761:role/hema-ghh"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::hematestpolicy",
                "arn:aws:s3:::hematestpolicy/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "172.31.0.0/16",
                        "192.168.2.6/16"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyEveryoneElse",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::hematestpolicy",
                "arn:aws:s3:::hematestpolicy/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "172.31.0.0/16",
                        "192.168.2.6/16"
                    ]
                },
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::975472539761:role/hema-ghh",
                        "arn:aws:iam::975472539761:root"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a VPC endpoint all outgoing connections would be via a public source (for public instances this would be their public IP via an internet gateway, and for private this would be via a NAT).

If you want to limit to allow objects to only be retrieved via the VPC you should look at using a [VPC endpoint for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html). By creating this and adding it to your route tables it will actually also provide a internal connection to S3 vs using the public internet.

Once you have this in place you can [create a bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html) that completely limits the requests to the source of that VPC endpoint.

For example the below policy would Deny access where not from the VPC Endpoint.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

Be aware that when using a bucket policy denying everything will restrict all access to that bucket (including management tasks) to only be available from that source VPC endpoint, so you should try to limit the scope of actions i.e. `GetObject`.